# How to add a dart package from github to my project?

Tags: dart

So I have a dart program and I want to add a dart package from github, not from the normal way of adding packages using the IDE package manager since the github version has the latest code.

What would be the process to do this?

---

This works for me in the real world.

```
name: game
description: A sample web application
dependencies:
  browser: any
  three:
    git:
      ref: master
      url: 'git://github.com/threeDart/three.dart.git'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add a dependency to your pubspec.yaml file which points directly to a git url.

For example this pubspec.yaml file adds a dependency to the kittens package:

```
name: My Dart program
description: Blah
dependencies:
  kittens:
    git: git://github.com/munificent/kittens.git
```

For more info see the [pubspec.yaml docs](http://pub.dartlang.org/doc/dependencies.html#git-packages).